# Why is this Java Swing key binding not working?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I've read through the Java tutorial on key bindings as well as half a dozen posts on this site with examples.  I can't for the life of me figure out why the following snippet is not working as expected:

```
    String ctrlSave = "CTRL Save";
    myPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s', InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), ctrlSave);
    myPanel.getActionMap().put(ctrlSave, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int returnVal = chooserFileSave.showSaveDialog(myPanel);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                fileSave = chooserFileSave.getSelectedFile();
                myPanel.getActiveRoute().saveToGPXFile(fileSave);
            }
        }
    });
```

If I replace this:

```
myPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s', InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), ctrlSave);
```

with this:

```
myPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), ctrlSave);
```

Then it works fine (of course, it is then 's' I have to hit and not "ctrl+s" as I desired).

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.  What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try using:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK);
```

Comment: No, I did not.  But it works!  Do you happen to know where in JavaDoc it is specified that VK_x (x being a char) is a constant?  The only VK_ prefixed constants I saw were those to do with special keys.  Thanks!

Comment: @DaveJohnson [`KeyStroke#getKeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29) states *"The "virtual key" constants defined in java.awt.event.KeyEvent can be used to specify the key code*" and then gives 3 examples...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand clearly, is it this what you are looking for: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah, that is the same page I saw.  It is just that all the examples given use "special keys" (space, ctrl, alt, etc), which led to me not realizing it could be used (and apparently *must* be used) for alphanumeric keys too.  I still wonder why 's' did not work?  The method calls for a `character`, and I gave it one with `'s'`.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Firstly, there is no `getKeyStroke(char, int)` method.  I suspect that it was begin cast to an `int`. If you want to use this verity, you need to use `getKeyStroke(Character, int)` instead.  As the docs say, the "virtual keys" are defined in `java.awt.event.KeyEvent` and the list 3 EXAMPLES - You could have used any "virtual key".  There are simple to many virtual keys to list.  Also, there is a difference between `Character` and `char`, you gave a `char`. To have worked you would have had to use `new Character('s')` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, I see where my error was.  However, even using `new Character('s')` does not work, which is still perplexing, but I guess it doesn't matter since `VK_S` does work.

Answer (score 1):

Your key binding is set to only when the component is selected. You need to change your input map to:

```
myPanel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s', InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), ctrlSave);
```